# Swift PKLassoTool callback and getting strokes from a selection

Tags: python, swift, pencilkit

Is there a way in Swift to run a callback function everytime the PKLassoTool is done selecting something. Also is there a way to get what the PKLassoTool selected.

I was using the `canvasViewDidEndUsingTool()` call back for canvasView but it doesn't activate when the lasso finishes a selection.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.